# Split String[] Into Two Other String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a `String[]` that looks like this where the first `String` is aways a property name and the second is the value:

```
String[] full = { "property1", "value1", "property2", "value2", "property3", "value3" };
```

I want to split that `String[]` into two other `String[]`s like this:

```
String[] properties = { "property1", "property2", "property3" };
String[] values = { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
```

Is there any way of doing this programmatically?

*PS: The number of property/value `Strings` in `full` may vary*

Comment: What is the logic behind this "split"? `s.startsWith("p")`?

Comment: They are accessed by their indices (i%2),,,,

Comment: Build a map, as Peter suggests, and then use the keySet() and values() methods on the Map object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest approach would just be:

```
String[] properties = new String[full.length / 2];
String[] values = new String[full.length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < properties.length; i++)
{
    properties[i] = full[i * 2];
    values[i] = full[i * 2 + 1];
}
```

It's hard to see how you'd be able to do it in a much simpler way than that. You probably want validation to start with that `full.length` is even.

Any reason for building two arrays instead of (say) a `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: I prefer using arrays so I can populate lists more easily. (just a old habit from Javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting into two arrays, its usually more useful to build a Map for fast lookup.

```
public static Map<String, String> asMap(String... keyValuePairs) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i += 2)
        map.put(keyValuePair[i], keyValuePait[i+1]);
    return map;
}

Map<String, String> map = asMap("property1", "value1",
                                "property2", "value2",
                                "property3", "value3");
String value3 = map.get("property3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the even members and odd members to 2 String[].
Bèfore that, you must assign the size of every substring.
if the orginal string has **odd** length, the substring contains odd members is length, and the substring, and the substring contains even members is length+1. else 2 substring is the same length = length /2.